# upgrade angular from version 2 to 4.0.0 - not latest

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to upgrade my angular project from v2 to v4.0.0 (I don't want to take the latest).
I've modified my package.json with :

```
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
```

but i got some errors :

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@4.4.0-RC.0 extraneous
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.0
├── @angular/compiler@4.3.6 
├─┬ @angular/compiler-cli@4.3.6 
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@^2.1.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.0
├── @angular/forms@4.3.6 
├── @angular/http@4.3.6 
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.3.6 
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.3.6 
├── @angular/platform-server@4.3.6 
├── @angular/router@4.3.6 
├── typescript@2.0.10 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.8
```

Is there any easy way to upgrade to a specific version?
Thx

Comment: no, you have to manually update each dependency

Comment: `yarn upgrade` is pretty good, but not to a specific version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to take the latest you should not use `^` in your dependencies list. remove all `^` from your dependencies like `"@angular/common": "4.0.0",`

```
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "4.0.0",
```

The `^` says you want to take incremental version after 4.0.0 which will be the latest. so you have to be strict checking. I think there are other errors you might face and have to remove them one by one.

Comment: Ah and if I want the latest of the 4.0.x, can I use something?

Comment: yes, I think you need to use `~` but not sure about it. search for symantic versioning and its use will help